# travis-ci triggers build only for master branch in github repo

Tags: github, travis-ci

I had two branches (`master` and `gh-pages`) in github git repo https://github.com/larrycai/LASO

According to the document http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/ , if the `.travis.yml` file exists in the branch, it will be triggered on all branches

While currently it is triggered for build in `master` branch only, see https://travis-ci.org/#!/larrycai/LASO/branch_summary

Do I must set white or black list in `.travis.yml` even I want to build for all branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gh-pages are ignored because most people want travis to ignore them.

Comment: Thank you, and here is related code (thx for Konstantin Haase)  https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-core/blob/master/lib/travis/model/request/approval.rb#L16 
I just simple to create `draft` branch, and always sync with gh-pages manually

Comment: While this is true, the answer below is actually more helpful since it actually provides a solution.

Answer (score 31):

According with [this merged pull request](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-core/pull/137) and [this documentation entry](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Building-Specific-Branches), you now can run tests on `gh-pages` branch by adding the branch to the whitelist:

```
branches:
  only:
    - gh-pages
```

Comment: You can include `- /.*/` in whitelist to still build all other branches.  (Not sure if `- /.*/` alone covers `- gh-pages`, I added both to be sure.)

Comment: I have the travis file only on a secondary branch (not master) because I want to learn Travis CI before merge with Master. Unfortunately Travis does not recognize the secondary branch. What am I missing? Thank you